# does kernel_initializer: even work for LSTM (C#. TensorFlow.NET)?

Tags: c#, lstm

```
Sequential model = keras.Sequential();
model.add(keras.Input(shape: (1, inputSize))); 
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units: numberOfHiddenUnits, kernel_initializer: 'glorot_uiform',   return_sequences: true));
```

```
kernel_initializer: 'glorot_uiform'<-- causes compile fails :


Program.cs(71,89,71,89): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
```

I expected  kernel_initializer  to work as the autocomplete ad the documentation suggests.